# How do I typecast an array of uint16_t into an array of uint8_t?

Tags: c, arrays, casting

I have a function that does an operation on an array of `uint8_t` of length 32. I want to pass it an array of `uint16_t` of length 16, and have it do the same operation on this array, byte-by-byte.

I tried doing this:

```
uint8_t byteArray[32];
void function(uint16_t *inArray)
{
    byteArray = (uint8_t *) inArray;
    ... do the byte-by-byte operations on byteArray
}
```

but I get the error:

> incompatible types when assigning to type 'uint8_t[32]' from type
>   'uint8_t *'

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm quite sure `byteArray` has a type, but it remains a mystery to us since you chose not to show it. Try `uint8_t *byteArray = ....`. Edit: I see it. Its above the code snippet. The proposal still stands.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> uint8_t byteArray[32];
> ```

You can't assign to `byteArray`. It's an array, thus not modifiable in C. You could use a pointer instead or rethink what you are doing: casting in itself is a code smell and should be avoided.

Since you mention you have a function operating on this, wouldn't it be better to have the function accept a parameter than using a global object ?

Comment: @w1res No, it isn't. A pointer and an array are vastly different objects. It just so happens that in some contexts an array transforms itself into a pointer to the first element.

Comment: I thought that when you write a function that accepts an array, it automatically gets converted to accept a pointer by the compiler.

Comment: @w1res Yes! But in this case `byteArray` is just an array, not a parameters name.

Answer (score 0):

An array is a collection of elements, it can't be asigned like that in C (and even less typecast). You can do it with a loop element by element, or rethink what you are doing to use the same type everywhere.